# Extract a QString from xml tag

Tags: xml, regex, string, xpath, qt4

I have this resulted QString from an http request, What I need to do is to extract only the string "一致" which is inside the tag

```
"TranslatedText>一致</TranslatedText>"
```

How to do this?

```
  <GetTranslationsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<From>en</From>
<Translations>
    <TranslationMatch>
        <Count>0</Count>
        <MatchDegree>100</MatchDegree>
        <MatchedOriginalText/>
        <Rating>5</Rating>
        <TranslatedText>一致</TranslatedText>
    </TranslationMatch>
</Translations>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a XPath query to do this.

Use the path:

```
/GetTranslationsResponse/Translations/TranslationMatch/TranslatedText/text()
```

To extract the value.

I'm not sure what platform/laguage you're using, so just investigate if QT has XPath support there.

Comment: can you explain how to use it?

Comment: Investigate XPath wtih C++... that XPath query will give you the string you're asking for. Take a look at QTXML.

Comment: so can you provide me the code to use XPath not just its query?

Comment: Can you search google? I told you the important bits. I'm not going to walk you through everything

Comment: I am doing that now :), but I would appreciate if you can help.

Comment: @Wazery - why not ask a question about how to use XPath and QT together?

Comment: @warren, I figured out it is not hard, you can see this page http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qxmlquery.html#running-xpath-expressions

Comment: @warren he did hint at QT, but his main question was how to extract the text.

Comment: @monksy - true, but it's also tagged `qt` :)

Comment: After using it with QtXMLQuery class, I got the following error "Error XTSE0010 in file:///home/qg/build/qg, at line 1, column 1: Parse error: Start tag expected."

Comment: Make a new question for that.

Comment: @monksy The error occurs because the path you wrote expects a start tag name GetTranslationsResponse not "GetTranslationsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" so how to fix this issue? .. P.S: It works when I change it to only GetTranslationsResponse

Comment: I used the XMl you posted and extracted the path out of it